# Using Java Spring, Is it possible to run a service that execute on the client side?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I want to create a simple strict service that tells the client if a PDF file is searchable or scanned images (not OCRed). Then I thought that the code is very simple and could run very fast, but the heavy lifting is in uploading the file especially if the file is large. Is there a way in Java and Spring to execute the code on the client's machine (if the client has JVM) by sending the code to the client to be executed and get the result?

Comment: would you want a website that you navigate to, to start running code on your desktop?  I would worry about the security implications of that

Comment: Let's say it's not a website but a local backend service that will be used by other services (micro-services architecture). So the client will be always myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for Java Web Start?
https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml

> The Java Web Start software allows you to download and run Java
>   applications from the web. The Java Web Start software:
>
> - Provides an easy, one-click activation of applications
> - Guarantees that you are always running the latest version of the application
> - Eliminates complicated installation or upgrade procedures

A signed Web Start application can request permissions to access local resources, native libraries and hardware.

To send the result back to server, you can simply have the Web Start application send it via HTTP[S]. The JNLP used to launch the Web Start application can be dynamically generated, so you can set parameters for the Web Start application, to have it send the parameter back to server, so you can identify which user session it is.

Comment: Yes, that exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!